# Search by more than one parameters in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to search by two parameters patient_id and email

Controller

```
function search_patients()
    {
        $data['query']=$this->UserModel->search_patients($this->input->post('search'));
        $this->load->view('search_patients_view',$data);
    }
```

Model

```
function search_patients($search)
{
return $query = $this->db->get_where('patient', array('patient_id'=> $search))->result();
}
```

Comment: you want to use AND or OR

Comment: Unclear Info. Please elaborate more.

Comment: OR
explain : any of one

Comment: your are using patient_id and above you are asking student_id

Comment: i have corrected ... its patient_id

Comment: Please help me...

Comment: let me know if you faced any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind your where like this

```
$where = '(patient_id ="' . $search . '" or email = "' . $search . '")';

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('patient');
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array(); // this will return you array
return $result;
```

Comment: Glad to help :)